# Can I use summation in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, linux, file-rename

How do I do summation in a regular expression?

Want to rename a Series from S02E01 to E61:

```
rename -n 's/S\d\dE(\d\d).*/E($1+60).mp4/' *.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the version of `rename` that uses Perl, you can use the `e` modifier to evaluate the replacement:

```
rename -n 's/S\d\dE(\d\d)/"E".($1+60)/e' *.mp4
```